selction in Illustrator
so am following one tutorial and there the teacher uses selection tool (v) but also he can select the corner point as well. in my case thats not happening. My understanding tells me u can only select the corner point when u use direct selection tool. I need guidance. please tell me what he did that he can use selection tool but also the corner point.
Thank you. the pink color one is from tutorial. another one is mine.



There is a preference under Illustrator>Settings (Preferences)> Selection and Anchor Display which needs to be checked on for anchor points to show when you have the Bounding Box enabled (View> Show Bounding Box).
If the Bounding Box is turned off then when you select something the anchor points will show whether you have the preference to Show Anchor Points turned on or off.


:O Thank you so much. I also discover u can hold ctrl while usng seletion tool. Thank you so much. U just saved me from a headache.
